# Oledb and Access. Should use Inner Join or C# loop?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I've restarted work on and old project. It's an access database with 6 tables. One of which is the main table, TableA. Here's how it kinda works.

TableA has a one to many with TableB, TableC and TableD.

TableD has a one to many with TableE.

TableE has a one to many with TableF.

At any point I will only need 1 record from tableA, but will always need the related records in Tables B, C, D, E and F.

I'm fine with making separate Select calls for Tables B and C, however the relationship for table D is interesting. For each record in Table A, Table D will have 4 to 5 records. For Each record in Table D, Table E will have 4 to 5 records. For each record in table E, Table F may have well over 100 records.

What I ultimately need to show the end user: Information from Table A, B, C and D. Info in Table E must be grouped by table D (I'm using a combobox) and information in Table F must be grouped by Table E (also a combobox) THEN separated into 1 of 4 groups.

Currently I have a database interface class that makes all my DB calls and returns a Binding list. I have recently developed an SQL query that performs an Inner join on TableD, TableE and TableF and was thinking that I would loop through the returned records, carefully creating my 6 separate BindingList.

My question: how could this be done better, while avoiding too many database hits? Am I wrong to assume that an inner join would be better than 4 separate DB calls?

Comment: I don't follow your data exactly, because I can't see it, but I would advise you to do as much heavy lifting as possible in the database, as this is for what it was intended.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I'll create a mockup visual for the DB as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the number of DB hits you should worry about. Worry firstly about using the right tool for the job. Relational databases are incredibly sophisticated when it comes to joining. Use this to the max. Crazy is the only word for doing joins outside the database.

Writing SQL to join up 5 tables will be much more fun if you use [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst) (disclaimer: which I wrote)